# How to identify whether a file is present in my webserver folder or not in android

Tags: android, webserver

**Background:**

I have a typical requirement of showing some images from web server on android. All the images in webserver are numbered sequentially and i am able to show the pictures in android as of now.

**Question :**
Is it possible to identify whether a image is present in webserver or not? if there is no image then i am getting no images and it is not showing me an error

Code:

public class ImageViewFromURLActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String URL =
    "http://mywebsite.com/private/image1.jpg";  //this is just an example
ImageView imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    // Execute the task
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you converting the image from server into the BitmapDrawable or Drawable? if yes you must get that Drawable null that means that image   is not present on server.

Comment: you can make a http header request

Comment: Hi @Amrut I have updated the code.could you pelase look into it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript and the `Image.onload` event to find out if an image can be loaded.

Example:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onerror = function() {
  // you can also do something in the error event handler
}
img.onload = function() {
  // display the image via JS here.
}
img.src = 'path/to/file';
```